# Export lon/lat from vector. GRASS GIS / QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, convert, latitude-longitude

I have some data as .shp (polygone representing Antarctica continent). I would like to know if there is a way to create a raster containing the lat/lon for each grid point ... Has somebody here tried to to that?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "each grid point". You have a polygon of Antarctica. Where does the grid come in?

Comment: If it is a Grid covering the Continent, use the "Polygon Centroid" Tool , and then convert that to a Raster... Could you show a picture of the Data?

Comment: Ok to be clearer: i don't have any grid so far. When i look to my layer metadata I obtain: 
Number of points: 0   Number of centroids: 1
Number of lines: 0      Number of boundaries: 2
Number of areas: 2    Number of islands: 2...

So, now i've got a nice raster ;) My question was really not clear ... I'll give it another try: A raster is a layer composed by pixels right ? How can I know the lat/lon of each pixel of my raster ? Is there a way to save the raster as a .csv / .txt file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description above, you have a polygon layer (not a raster). You can easily make a regular grid covering that polygon with the QGIS tool "Vector->Research Tools->Vector Grid". Then, as GISJohnECS explained, you can get the centroids of each grid cell. This will create a third vector points layer. Finally, open the Field Calculator for this point layer, and use the geometry functions $x and $y to add two columns for longitude and latitude. You can read some more details in the [QGIS documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html). That will give you all the long/lats of each centroid of all the cells in your (vector) polygon grid.

However, can I suggest you explain what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Well put, I am editing my question adding something to it, hoepfully one of our solutions is what he is looking for

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps add more detail to your question, a preview of your .shp file would be nice. Assuming your .shp is a polygon of Antarctica divided into grids, and you want the Lat/Lon of each grid, to convert into a raster, Use the **Go to the menu -> Vector -> Geometry tools -> polygon centroid and create a centroid point layer.**

And then use the [Interpolation Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_interpolation.html) to convert your centroid file to a Raster, using whatever attribute value you wish. If the attribute value from your polygon file is not attributed to your Centroid Output, just use a [spatial join](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html)

Adding on based on your comment, Micha has added an answer assuming you just meant you wanted the XY values from a vector grid, but, assuming you want XY values from a raster, here is my take from this [Tutorial](http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/19/54-how-to-sample-raster-datasets-using-points-in-quantum-gis-qgis.html) use the Regular points Tool found in **Vector->Research Tools-> Regular Points** this tool will get regular points in a grid format separated by a defined distance, if you want points in each grid you can try define the distance as the width of each pixel *understand if you have a high resolution raster it may crash, normally I just define a number of points like 100000 or something*

You have your raster:
[image]

Run the Regular Points Tool:
[image]

Heres the output:
[image]

And then save this layer as a CSV and have the geometry as X,Y
[image]

This will give you X,Y locations of each point that was generated, that may not be from each pixel though... As i mentioned this assumes you really want the XY values for pixels... But also read Michas Answer to see if thats what you wanted

Comment: So, now i've got a nice raster, thanks ;) My question was really not clear ... I'll give it another try: A raster is a layer composed by pixels right ? How can I know the lat/lon of each pixel of my raster ? And write those lat/lon in .txt/.csv file ?

Comment: @P.Huot I think I may have a solution, once I finish work I will post one for you, unless someone else jumps in first.

Comment: @P.Huot I edited, let me know if it helps otherwise Mocha has added an answer

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, i can't try it right now but it seems to be what i wanted to do. If i fail at this method, there is still Micha's one ;)